# Using google sheet to add Calendar event, but don't want to create if an event is already there

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a reservation form in Google forms which then creates a calendar invite to "book the reservation".  However, I want to run a validation against the dates requested to ensure there isn't already an event on the calendar during that same time.  For example, The user enters Check Date of July 20th and Check out date of July 27, but on the calendar, there is already an event for July 23-25.  How do I create this validation and return a validation to the user in the google form and have them select different dates.  I have copied the code I have (that currently works) to create a calendar invite from the google form.

```
   function fncName()
  var Cal = calendar.app.getcalenderbyID('beachcondoo@gmail.com')
  var events = cal.getEvents(starttime, endtime)
 

function createCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('oibeachcondo@gmail.com');
 
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
 
  var complete = "Done";
 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[1]; //Email Address
    var name = row[2];  //Name
    var phone = row[3]; //Phone Number
    var guests = row[4];  //# of Guests
    var payment = row[7];  //Payment Preference
    var checkin = new Date(row[8]);  //Checkin Date
    var checkout = new Date(row[9]); //Checkout Date
    var eventID = row[10]; //event marked Done
   
    if (eventID != complete) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      calendar.createEvent('\Ocean Isle Beach Condo Reserved', checkin, checkout, {
        description: payment + '\r-' + name + '\r-' + phone + '\r-' + email + '\r-' + guests +'\guests'
      });
    
      currentCell.setValue(complete);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Start with doing search and run through the return list to see if there are any overlapping  times.

Comment: Ok, I am starting to figure it out, thanks!  I now have this code that pulls all the calendar dates back into a log, but I don't know how to now search the 'checkin' and 'checkout' dates against these to confirm they aren't taken

Comment: Also, why does my post have 2 negative votes?  Am I doing something wrong?  Clearly new to this, but trying to figure it out as I go.

Comment: You probably want to spend some time learning about Date()s in Javascript/GoogleAppsScript they can be a bit difficult to grasp at first.  There's two Date() methods that return a value that make it possible to compare them and those method art getTime() and valueOf().  Once you understand how to deal with Dates then determine a startTime value and and endtime value and you can begin to address how to figure out how to determine if there are conflicts between schduled and unscheduled events.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!!  I'll start that today!

Answer (score 0):

### Consideration

You can easily build a check based on the Start and End date using this method: [`.getEvents(startTime, endTime)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime).

The check will consist in looking for events in the user defined timeframe, if there are any, the creation will fail.

However, there is no way to return the validation check result to the user on the Google Form.

### A possible workaround

You will have to implement a different way to notify your user that the selected timeframe is not available.

### Using triggers

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) are the best way to automate your processes in G Suite. Let's assume that your environment is built like this:

Form and Calendar

The Form will represent the User interface, the Calendar your event database.

A submission to a form will trigger an event creation based on the validation function result.

To trigger this validation you will have to use an [`.onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) trigger.

Now your validation function will produce two possible scenarios:

#### Event Creation failed

If the event is overlapping on existing events in your calendar the creation cannot be created. You can notify your user sending an email with GAS `MailApp` saying that the selected timeframe is unavailable. You can also invite the user to fill the form again selecting a different timeframe attaching the Form's link to the email.

#### Event Creation success

If the event is not overlapping any existing event, i.e. the getEvents(startTime, endTime) didn't return any event, you can proceed to create the event with your script.

### References

[Calendar App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app)

[Gmail App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)

[Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)